# update whole json by remove all elements from array except the one at given array index

Tags: arrays, json, jq, edit

Whole json structure to be kept, but in one array I'd like to remove all values but one on given index.

Input:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": [11,22,33,44]
    }
    
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": [22]
    }
    
}
```

**All I have on input to identify item to be deleted is its index in array.**

I thought:

```
.a.b|=map(select(<SELECT_WHAT?>))
```

maybe I could do `($val | index(.)) == <desiredIndex>` within select, but with |= I don't know how to declare variable, and it does not seem very efficient ...

Comment: No. I don't want to remove by value, or remove by index, I want to retain value at given index. (sorry, poorly formulated question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $i is the relevant index:

```
.a.b |= [.[$i]]
```

For example:

```
jq --argjson i 1 '.a.b |= [.[$i]]' input.json
```

Comment: We were working concurrently.  I was going for simplicity (w.r.t. number of indices) and generality (w.r.t. method of specifying the index).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select by indices, simply use the array value iterator syntax for specifying the indices to retain

```
.a.b |= [ .[1, 2] ]
```

---

The following updates were provided before the question as modified to clear out the actual requirements. Retaining it for posterity

**Selecting by value**

```
.a.b |= map(select(. == 22))
```

**Deleting by indices**

or if you want to delete by indices *if* they are already known, use `del()` with the path expression as the indices to be deleted. For e.g. the following deletes values at indices 1,2

```
.a.b |= del(.[1, 2])
```

Comment: What if I want to select specified index? I don't know what is at this index.